# WPF: DataGridTemplateColumn not to affect the last row

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, bold, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am using .net4.0. I have a DataGrid with 5 cols. I added DataGridTemplateColumn to add "U" and "D" buttons for Update & Delete.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="U" ToolTip="Update" x:Name="btnUpdate" Click="btnUpdate_Click"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="D" ToolTip="Delete" x:Name="btnDelete" Click="btnDelete_Click"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My last row in the grid is just for displaying total values of each col. I don't want the 2 btns in that last row of the grid. Is it possible to hide those btns of the last row.

I also want to have all text Bold of that last row.

How are both the above thigns possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a proeprty and added a trigger in DataGridTemplate and this solved my issue.

Thanks for your time and efforts.